# Spring security OAuth2 UserRedirectRequiredException

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to setup OAuth2 with spring security for Google App Engine aplication. Here is my OAuth2 config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class OAuth2Config {

@Bean
public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails googleOAuth2Details() {
    AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails googleOAuth2Details = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();

    googleOAuth2Details.setAuthenticationScheme(form);
    googleOAuth2Details.setClientAuthenticationScheme(form);
    googleOAuth2Details.setClientId("*********************");
    googleOAuth2Details.setClientSecret("*********************");
    googleOAuth2Details.setUserAuthorizationUri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth");
    googleOAuth2Details.setAccessTokenUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token");
    googleOAuth2Details.setScope(asList("openid"));
    return googleOAuth2Details;
}

@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
@Resource
private OAuth2ClientContext oAuth2ClientContext;

@Bean
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public OAuth2RestOperations googleOAuth2RestTemplate() {
    return new OAuth2RestTemplate(googleOAuth2Details(), oAuth2ClientContext);
}
```

}

Scpring security working OK, but when I am trying to login I am gettting following exeption:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException: A redirect is required to get the users approval
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.getRedirectForAuthorization(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:347)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:194)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainNewAccessTokenInternal(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:142)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.createRequest(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:515)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:128)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:482)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:264)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:132)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:120)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.getForEntity(Unknown Source)
at com.evogro.farmino.security.OpenIDConnectAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OpenIDConnectAuthenticationFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: Why is your rest template request scoped (it ain't going to work unless you can inject an access token in every request)?

Comment: In other case, google app engine throws an exception that RestTemplate is not Serializable. Know how to fix it?

Comment: What "other case" is that? What version of Spring OAuth are you using anyway?

Comment: The other case is when rest template session scoped. So Spring tries to save rest template to session, but app engine throws an exception that RestTemplate is not Serializable. Spring OAuth version = 2.0.6.RELEASE

Comment: So don't put it in session scope. AFAIK singleton scope is fine (the `OAuth2ClientContext` that you injected is already session scoped).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from the scope issue discussed in comments I imagine your app is missing an `OAuth2ClientContextFilter` (that's what normally handles those exceptions). Just put it in your web.xml if you have one, or register it with the servlet context. From the [user guide](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html):

> Creates a filter bean (with ID oauth2ClientContextFilter) to store the current request and context. ... The filter has to be wired into the application (e.g. using a Servlet initializer or web.xml configuration for a DelegatingFilterProxy with the same name).

Comment: Another possible reason is that your filter is there but in placed in the wrong place in a filter chain. When deploying to app servers such as Glassfish filters appear to get registered in reverse order to the order they are defined when running in a standalone app, which can cause a whole raft of issues.

Comment: @DaveSyer In spring 5, OAuth2ClientContextFilter has been removed. Spring uses OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter and OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter. However OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter needs an explicit URL with {registrationId} to make a correct request to Auth server.Is there any way , I can redirect implicitly when user is trying to access my web page? I do not want him to click on "login with google" and then pass registration id.I want it to be implicit.

Comment: I'm pretty sure redirect to the auth server is the default with the Spring Security 5 oauth2Login() feature. Maybe it would be better to ask about that explicitly in another post?