# Spring OAuth2 Client Redirect to Auth Server doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0

When I try to access my own OAuth2 secured REST API using an authorization code, I don't get redirected to the API and get this error:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException: A redirect is required to get the users approval
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.getRedirectForAuthorization(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:359)
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:205)
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainNewAccessTokenInternal(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:142)
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:118)
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221)
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173)
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.createRequest(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:105)
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:592)
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:128)
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:289)
 at hello.CustomerServiceImpl.getCustomer(CustomerServiceImpl.java:63)
 at WICKET_hello.CustomerServiceImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$f879347b.invoke(<generated>)
 at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
 at org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory$CGLibInterceptor.intercept(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:317)
 at WICKET_hello.CustomerServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$1fb40ae.getCustomer(<generated>)
 at hello.CustomerPage.<init>(CustomerPage.java:16)
```

My Spring service looks like this:

```
@Service
```

@EnableOAuth2Client
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

```
@Value("http://localhost:3010")
private String baseUrl;

@Value("http://localhost:3010/oauth/authorize")
private String authorizeUrl;

@Value("http://localhost:3010/oauth/token")
private String tokenUrl;

@Value("client")
private String clientId;

@Value("secret")
private String clientSecret;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("restTemplate")
private OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate;

@Bean
private OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate() {
    AccessTokenRequest atr = new DefaultAccessTokenRequest();
    return new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource(), new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(atr));
}

private OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource() {
    AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails resource = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
    resource.setAccessTokenUri(tokenUrl);
    resource.setUserAuthorizationUri(authorizeUrl);
    resource.setClientId(clientId);
    resource.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
    return resource;
}

@Override
public Customer getCustomer() {
    String requestUrl = baseUrl + "/api/customer";
    ResponseEntity<Customer> entity = restTemplate.getForEntity(requestUrl, Customer.class);
    return entity.getBody();
}
```

}

Comment: Did you check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544055/spring-security-oauth2-userredirectrequiredexception ?

Comment: I tried that, but then it throws a NullPointerException `at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:125)` instead. (line 9 in the old stack trace)

Comment: I fixed it by adding `org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener` to my web.xml but now I get the same UserRedirectRequiredException as above.